# CSS in tab - last TR TD

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

```
<table id="tab">

<tr> <td>11</td> <td>22</td> </tr>

<tr> <td>33</td> <td>44</td> </tr>

<tr> <td>55</td> <td>66</td> </tr>

</table>

#tab td {
border: solid 2px red;
padding: 10px;
}

#tab td {
background-color: green;
}
```

I would like that only in last TR TD was GREEN - **55** and **66**. TD with 11, 22, 33, 44 must be white.

I generate this table with PHP - I must use only CSS or jQuery.

```
#tab td:last {
background-color: green;
}
```

doesn't work.

**LIVE:** http://jsfiddle.net/Rx2De/

Comment: Have you tried "tr:last-child td" instead of just ":last"? IE6 won't understand, but I think from IE7 up it works.

Comment: @Pointy - I don't think `:last-child` is supported until IE9: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t35

Comment: You're right - that's weird; something recently convinced me otherwise but I don't recall what it was :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard-compliant solution for that is:

```
#tab tr:last-child td {
    background-color: green;
}
```

However it isn't supported in IE6-8. Fot them you can use jQuery snippet:

```
$(function(){
    $('#tab tr:last td').css('background', 'green');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want to use the `:last-child` pseudo class.  And you would want to apply that on the tr not the td.

```
#tab tr:last-child {
  background-color: green;
}
```

here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Rx2De/1/

Answer (score 2):

write like this

```
#tab tr:last-child td {
background-color: green;
}
```

but is not work in IE

or you write like this:

```
#tab tr + tr + tr td {
    background-color: green;
    }
```

check this http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/Rx2De/7/

it's work on IE also